# Как в обработчик кнопки ButtonX_Clicks получить доступ к полям конструктора объекта

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Так не работает:) Ошибка по понятным причинам]

[image: Вот мои поля и конструктор]

Я создаю объект в другом методе, обычно я в другие методы отправлял аргументы с объектами что бы с ними можно было работать в методе, а тут не понимаю как делать.
Ведь передача аргументами как на картинке не будет работать.

Comment: вы аргументы в поля сохраняете, вот с полями и работайте

Comment: В следующий раз, пожалуйста, приводите код в текстовом виде, не картинками